# RequireJS in Webstorm w/ CDNs: How do I avoid these "Cannot resolve directory" errors?

Tags: requirejs, webstorm

[image: Image of errors]

I am developing in Webstorm, using RequireJS and directing the paths to CDNs. Webstorm produces all kinds of "Cannot resolve directory" errors, as seen in the above image. The paths work when I run the app, it's just a matter of Webstorm rustling my jimmies with false errors. `Alt-enter` doesn't present any relevant fixes.

In related questions, the answer is to mark the directory as a resource, but I don't see how I can do that when it is a remote website. I already have the libraries themselves loaded:

[image: Image of loaded external libraries]

**How do I get Webstorm to accept these paths as legitimate? Failing that, how do I tell it to ignore this error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs in require() are not currently supported. Please vote for [WEB-2467](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2467).
The only way to get rid of the error is suppressing error highlighting for this file: click the Hector icon in the lower right corner and then move the slider to change the Highlighting level to None. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html